# How do I filter multiple values in a single dataset with one parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

In using Report Builder I have a parameter called Clinician and then I have a dataset with 3 different clinician categories, InfantClinician, PreschoolClinician and I need to have all 3 of them work with the parameter. I cant seem to find online exactly how to do this. With what I have below I do not get any value in my results when running the report.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual studio are you using here? Those images look like a really old version (more like BIDS than SSDT). If you are using a completely unsupported version you should be tagging that, as it's really important information. The SQL you have isn't parameterised either, if you want parameterised shouldn't it be?

Comment: I'm using Report Builder 14.

Comment: Are you perhaps using Windows XP then? Report Builder 14 was released in 2016, if I recall correctly. What about my question about the lack of parametrisation in your query?

Comment: No its windows 10. The report builder is hosted. I tried adding WHERE ChildClinician IN (@Clinician) or InfantClinician IN (@Clinician) or PreschoolClinician IN (@Clinician) but still doesnt work.

Comment: Did you remove the dataset filters after you parameterised your query? Your dataset filter will only include a record where all three are true.

Comment: Your `WHERE ChildClinician IN (@Clinician) or InfantClinician IN (@Clinician) or PreschoolClinician IN (@Clinician)` should work but you would need to remove the 3 Dataset Filters (which all need to match to show a record as Alan mentioned).

Comment: I took the filter out of it and just kept the where clause.